# JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: ubuntu, java-home

I'm very new to Ubuntu, so I would appreciate some help.

I am installing Apache ActiveMQ, and for this I need maven to be installed.
First I installed jdk and jre java packages, and edited /etc/profile like the following:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_09 
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin 
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_09 
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin 
export JAVA_HOME 
export JRE_HOME 
export PATH
```

but when I installed maven, and it gave me JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
So after a small research, I edited /etc/bash.bashrc and included the following:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_09 
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin 
export PATH
```

And now it displays:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_0.9/bin/java/bin/java
```

I'm sure my mistake is trivial, but it's the first time I use ubuntu
So I couldn't figure it out...
I appreciate any help

Comment: i think duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11021053

Comment: I had the same problem and the solution was this [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/maven-java_home-is-not-defined-correctly-on-mac-osx/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's clearly mentioning 
`we cannot execute /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_0.9/bin/java/bin/java`

This path indeed doesn't exist. If you have downloaded zip distribution of JDK 1.7 point your path to extracted Java folder bin directory.

If you are already able to run `java` from `bash`, just type `which java`, that should print the `installed folder`

Comment: Hi @Nitin... thx for reply. Actually the path to the extracted java folder is /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_09, and the bin directory is inside it. Ain't my code valid in this case?

Comment: i think this is great http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019231/error-java-home-is-not-defined-correctly-in-building-jikes-rvm/11021053#11021053

Comment: Thx @Nitin... the problem is solved... it turned out that I had misconfigured a different file...

Comment: @user1793538 - please mention the name of the file if you remember. It will help other people.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was due to the carriage return character being appended to the file where the JAVA_HOME variable was declared making the error harder to track down:

```
cat -A /etc/environment
```

The output:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25^M$
TOMCAT_HOME=/usr/tomcat7^M$
M2_HOME=/usr/maven
```

The fix:

```
perl -pi -e "s/\015//g" /etc/environment
```