# build openjdk on mac "JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly"

Tags: jvm, java

I am building openjdk on MAC and facing a problem like this:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /NO_BOOTDIR/bin/java
```

the OS of my mac is 10.10.2.

the openjdk is

```
openjdk-7u40-fcs-src-b43-26_aug_2013
```

the ALT_BOOTDIR

```
export ALT_BOOTDIR=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

the $JAVA_HOME

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

when I set JAVA_HOME and run 'make sanity', the error is like this:

```
ERROR: Your JAVA_HOME environment variable is set.  This will
   most likely cause the build to fail.  Please unset it
   and start your build again.
```

so I have to unset it and no matter I unset it or not, the error appears.

any ideas?

thinks.

Comment: As far i know, java home should be `/1.7.0.jdk`, not `/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-yosemite-10-10-mavericks-10-9-mountain-lion-10

Comment: thanks for your answers. I am trying to build a JVM based on previous idk so the BOOTDIR should be the path of the previous JDK. And in my opinion, the important thing is not the JAVA_HOME which must be unset.

Answer (score 11):

Before setting the path make sure that java is installed by checking the directory

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<version>.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<version>.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME
```

If it OpenJDK is missing you can install it through [brew](https://brew.sh)

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
```

There should be symlinks in `/usr/bin` to `java` and `javac`

Comment: I think you'll find java and javac should generally be symlinked from /usr/bin

Comment: The latest Brew API requires `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk11`